# Regular expression to calculate T[+/-]n date where n= [1,2,3,4...] using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a field name Date having value like T, T+1, T+2,T-2,T-1 etc. As per Operator(+/-) and operand2(n) i need to perform calculation like...

```
if 
  T then date.today()
  T+n then date.today()+ timedelta(days=n)
  T-n then date.today()- timedelta(days=n)
```

In Perl i use to do...

```
if (var =~ /T/) { today();}
if (var =~ /T\+(\d+)/) { today()+$1;}
if (var =~ /T\-(\d+)/) { today()-$1;}
```

I want to use regular expression using Python in same way. Can anybody help me pls.

Comment: Wanted to know how to use Regular Expression in IF condition to get group() value?

Comment: Regular expression is not the way to do this in python.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import re
>>>
>>> def t(var):
...     today = datetime.date.today()
...     if var == 'T':
...         return today
...     matched = re.search(r'T\+(\d+)', var)
...     if matched:
...         return today + datetime.timedelta(int(matched.group(1)))
...     matched = re.search(r'T-(\d+)', var)
...     if matched:
...         return today - datetime.timedelta(int(matched.group(1)))
...
>>> t('T')
datetime.date(2013, 6, 30)
>>> t('T+1')
datetime.date(2013, 7, 1)
>>> t('T-1')
datetime.date(2013, 6, 29)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: I know it and i have done like this but my concern was "How to use regular expression check under IF condition" like.. *if (matched = re.search(r'T\+(\d+)', var)): print matched.group(1),* instead of assigning search result (t/f) to var and then use check var under IF?

Comment: You want to make an assignment inside the `if` conditional? you don't do that in python.

Answer (score 0):

The same principals apply in Python, although the "spelling" is different.

In Python regular expressions are done with the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Date handling is done with the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
day = date.today()
if len(var)==3:
    delta = timedelta(int(var[2:]))
    if var[1]=='+':
        day += delta
    elif var[1]=='-':
        day -= delta
```

you can use `operator` module for the last `if`:

```
from operator import add, sub
day = {'+': add, '-': sub}[var[1]](day, delta)
```